# Estimating the norm of a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: matrix-calculus, c-star-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\tau: A \to \mathbb{C}$ a bounded functional. Let $u = [u_{i,j}] \in M_n(A)$ be a unitary matrix and consider the matrix $m = [\tau(u_{i,j})] \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Can we find a good estimate for $\|m\|?$

For example, it would be convenient if I have the following estimate
$$\|m\| \le \|\tau\|.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $m = (\text{id}_n \otimes \tau)(u)$. Bounded functionals are automatically completely bounded, with $\|\text{id}_n \otimes \tau\| = \|\tau\|$. So now you've got that
$$\|m\| =\|\text{id}_n \otimes \tau(u)\| \leq \|\text{id}_n \otimes \tau\|\|u\| = \|\tau\|. $$

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with completely bounded maps, but I do know what completely positive maps are. Is there maybe a solution that uses this notion?

Comment: completely bounded maps are just like c.p. maps, except we work with boundedness rather than positivity. If $\phi: S \to T$ is a map between operator spaces (instead of systems), we insist that $\sup_n\|\text{id}_n \otimes \phi\| < \infty$ (instead of having $\text{id}_n \otimes \phi$ be positive for each $n$). The proof that functionals are completely bounded is quite direct, but I'll just refer you to the appendix in Brown & Ozawa.

Comment: If your functional $\tau$ is a positive functional, its completely positive. Then the same argument I've written down applies.

Comment: I'll add that when you've got a positive functional, its norm is given by $\|\tau\| = \tau(1)$, in the case that you've got a unit. From here its not too hard to convince yourself that $\|\text{id}_n\otimes \tau\| = \|\tau\|$.

Comment: Alright. Now I know where to look. Good enough for me! Thanks for your answer!